# Can I put link from custom html to wrapper module?

Tags: module, jhtml, weblinks, joomla-3.2

Here it is. I have a custom html with some mouse hover js function. So, when I click on that fade in 'view' button, I want to display embedded video in wrapper module?

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange :-). You should add some code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using JCE MediaBox plugins. It's the easiest way, at least for now. Finally, I have a pop up window now in my site.

So, my question has an answer now. But if anyone have other good solution (without installing any plugins), I will revert this answer, mark others as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your IFRAME with video code (for example from youtube) to your custom html module. You just need to disable cleaning code from iframes. If you are using TinyMCE you can do it in TinyMCE plugin settings. Just remove `iframe` from `Prohibited Elements` setting and click on save. Then you can add your iframe into articles and custom html module.